# Create a rule for symbology of a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, color, rule

I want to create a rule for applying a particular symbology to a raster in QGIS. I do not know if this is possible. In detail, I would like to classify (as discrete) values of a raster1 based on its values and those of another raster (raster2). Both rasters are completely overlapping.

As an example, I want pixels colored in green when values of raster2 are 1 and values of raster1 are <= 5 otherwise pixels must be in red; similarly when values of raster2 are 2 and values of raster1 are <=1.5 color pixels in green otherwise in red; etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [Raster Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) to create a new (binary) raster based on the conditions you have with the following expression that creates a value 1 if one of the conditions is fulfilled (green) or 0 (red) if none of the conditions is fulfilled. You can add more lines for your further conditions:

   ```
   "raster2@1" = 1 and "raster1@1" <=5 or
   "raster2@1" = 2 and "raster1@1" <=1.5
   ```
2. The resulting raster has values of 0 or 1. Set this raster's color to Singleband pseudocolor (see screenshot) and use a color ramp from red to green.

By the way: red/green colors can be problematic due to color blindness issues, see e.g.:

> It’s important to emphasize here that using red and green, while
> intuitive, should be avoided.
> https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

*Resulting raster, clicked a green pixel (value=1, color=green) with underlaying raster1=1.33883 and raster2=1:*
[image]

Comment: Just a correction. It doesn't work with the formulation you posted. I have changed it:
IF(("raster2@1" = 1) and ("raster1@1" <=5)) or
IF(("raster2@1" = 2) and ("raster1@1" <=1.5))